# Couldn't find Product with 'id'= when adding products to Cart in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shopping-cart

When I try to add products to a Cart in a App that I'm building I always get this error `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=` . According to Better Errors this is happening in the first line on the Create method in my `product_items_controller.rb`as seen below.

```
def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    if @product_item.save
        redirect_to root_url, notice:'Product added to Cart'
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

I changed the first line to : `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` but that didn't correct the error.

Earlier tonight I modified the `Add to Cart`button code
 from :`<%= button_to product_items_path(product_id: product) do %>` to `<%= button_to product_items_path( @product) do %>`

This is the code for the Add to Cart button as it is now.

```
 <%= button_to product_items_path( @product) do %>
   <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart
 <% end %>
```

**UPDATE, ADDED ROUTES.rb**

here is the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :categories
 resources :labels
 resources :products

 resources :carts
 resources :product_items
 resources :orders

 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
 root 'pages#index'

end
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

here is the `cart.rb`which holds the add_product method

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
end

def total_price_usd
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price_usd}
end

def total_price_isl
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price_isl}
end
end
```

**UPDATE**

here is the link to the github repo https://github.com/DadiHall/hlinreykdal

I have created all product through Active Admin, and that works like it should work.
Am I missing something here?
I can't figure out why this error keeps coming.

Comment: To which action does the route `product_items_path( @product)` map to? Can you post your routes.rb? And what are `@cart` and `product` inside `create` action?

Comment: Hi, I´ve added the routes.rb and the cart.rb.... the add_product method is in the cart.rb

Comment: What is `product` in the second line of `create` action?

Comment: It´s the id of the product item

Comment: Maybe You want to check out the GitHub repo, I added the link to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following line of code.

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

`params[:product_id]`is `nil` cause its not present in the `params` hash. To know what `params` holds, you can do something like this.

```
def create
  render text: params
end
```

Now, if you try to create a new `product_item`, you will find the params passed to the `create` action.

However if you want `product_id` to be passed to the `create` action, you need `nested` routes.

```
resources :products do
  resources :product_items
end
```

And change your html as

```
<%= button_to product_product_items_path( @product) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart
<% end %>
```

You can find the routes generated by running `rake routes`.

In the second line of the `creation` action,

```
@product_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
```

I am not sure what `product` is. Should it be

```
@product_item = @cart.add_product(@product.id)
```

?

Comment: If I use nested routes I get `undefined method 'product_items_path'` for the add to cart button, this is the code for the button `  <%= button_to product_items_path( @product) do %>`

Comment: Sorry My Bad.... it works I just had to change the path to `product_product_items_path( @product)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad that it helped.